# Using Jenkins as a service on Cloudbees

Tags: cloudbees

I am new to Cloudbees and have been trying to find out how I can run an existing Jboss Portal Server based application which we run in our locally hosted CI in Cloudbees infrastructure.

Our stack has the following components

- JDK 1.6 JBoss
- Portal Server (EPP 4.3)
- Oracle Express Edition (XE)

Would appreciate any help from the community to ensure that I dont discard the option of running Jenkins in the cloud on the Cloudbees platform without proper research.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to setup your build job to install and start the adequate runtime

JDK 6 is available as part of CloudBees runtimes, you can then use /private repository to store EPP 4.3 as a zip and expand to /tmp during a pre-build step

Same principle applies to your database, but I'm not sure you can install Oracle XE without user interaction and without being root. I remember doing this myself some years ago on ubuntu and was not as trivial as just unzipping a binary distro.

Is your code tied to this DB ? Or are you using some DB abstraction layer that you could use to test using another DB runtime (mysql / postgres) ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand the approach suggested by you (and yes we can abstract to have it running against mysql instead of oracle xe). Do I get access to a command line with Cloudbees or do I configure the download/unzip as part of my jenkins job steps?